# Redis::TimeoutError in Rails application

Tags: ruby, redis, timeout

I keep getting Redis::Timeout error in my application (both in UI and in background jobs). I am using AWS ElastiCache service for Redis.

This is how I create a Redis connection. In my config/application.rb , I have:

```
$redis = Redis.new(host: REDIS_HOST, port: REDIS_PORT, db: REDIS_DB)
```

How can I avoid getting timeout errors? I am using the default connection settings as follows:

```
> $redis.client.options[:reconnect_attempts]
 => 1 
> $redis.client.options[:timeout]
 => 5.0 
> $redis.client.options[:tcp_keepalive]
 => 0 
> $redis.client.options[:inherit_socket]
 => false
```

Comment: Under which circumstances are you getting timeouts? On any attempt?

Comment: It happens sporadically and I haven't been able to reproduce it reliably. I get to know about it when exception notification is sent.

Comment: Can you check the memory usage of your Ruby app when that happens? Does it happen when the garbage collector runs?

Comment: Did you manage to figure  this out ?

Comment: Which Redis gem and in what context is it used (i.e., is your Redis connection wrapped within a different library/gem? is the Redis server local? are you using ssl tunneling for the Redis connections?)? Did you consider using more reconnection attempts (i.e., iodine's Redis engine infinitely attempts to reconnect, keeping any unsent messages in the internal queue)?

Comment: Hi, Did try increasing the retry count and timeout value?

Answer (score 1):

You should pool your Redis connections with the help of the [Connection Pool Gem](https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool) and increase the timeout value if the problem persists:

```
ConnectionPool.new(size: 5, timeout: 3) {Redis.new({:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379, :db => 1, :timeout => 240})}
```

[Redis Gem](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb)